# CyanogenMod 13 compiling error.

Tags: android, android-source, cyanogenmod

I'm trying to port CM13 to LG K7, and it stopped with this error:

```
    Generating digraph...
    Finding vertex sequence...
   Reversing backward edges...
  0/0 dependencies (0.00%) were violated; 0 source blocks stashed.
Improving vertex order...
Reticulating splines...
max stashed blocks: 0  (0 bytes), limit: <unknown>

using prebuilt boot.img from BOOTABLE_IMAGES...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 1772, in <module>
    main(sys.argv[1:])
  File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 1727, in main
    WriteFullOTAPackage(input_zip, output_zip)
  File "./build/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files", line 710, in WriteFullOTAPackage
    common.CheckSize(boot_img.data, "boot.img", OPTIONS.info_dict)
  File "/home/taco/android/system/build/tools/releasetools/common.py", line 701, in CheckSize
    p = info_dict["fstab"][mount_point]
KeyError: '/boot'
build/core/Makefile:1912: recipe for target '/home/taco/android/system/out/target/product/m1/cm_m1-ota-7a8eeaa18d.zip' failed
make: *** [/home/taco/android/system/out/target/product/m1/cm_m1-ota-7a8eeaa18d.zip] Error 1
make: Leaving directory '/home/taco/android/system'

#### make failed to build some targets (11:25 (mm:ss)) ####

taco@taco-VirtualBox:~/android/system$
```

i couldn't resolve this issue by my self.

Comment: Obviously the script to generate the ota image from target files zip failed. Do you actually need the ota zip? The images you need to flash the device should be already built at this point. If you need it, the whole build output would be helpful.

Comment: The ota zip is generate at this directory: /home/taco/android/system/out/target/product/m1/obj/PACKAGING/target_files_intermediates/           I re-synced and hard reset the repo and still didn't work.